# Creating a dictionary schema with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to store a dictionary of objects using Mongoose. Realizing that I lose the change detection for saving with using the Mixed type, I was hoping I could create a schema that would not require the Mixed type.

There are plenty of examples of creating schemas for arrays of objects, but not dictionaries of objects. Is it possible to do this?

Format:

```
{
    ObjectId : {
        "attempts" : {
            "response" : String,
            "timestamp" : Date
        },
        "complete" : Boolean
    }
}
```

Comment: A schema like you show is fine, but I don't understand why you have `ObjectId` in your example format.

Comment: It just so happens that the string I am using as the key is an ObjectId

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no support for dictionary in `mongoose`. Field name can't be dynamic in a schema. You should go with a raw object(embedded document) and implement it as a dictionary. But there will be no validation from `mongoose` and use [markModified](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_embedded_EmbeddedDocument-markModified) before saving whenever you have changed that field

```
var fooSchema=mongoose.Schema({name:String, dic:{}});
//dic is your dictionary
```

Comment: How can I strict key and value data types?

Answer (score 3):

Update: from 5.1 mongoose have a Map type: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps

Answer (score 0):

You can have your dictionary like this with ***meta*** being a dictionary:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  meta: {
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
  first_name:  String,
  last_name: String,
  profile_pic:   String,
  gender: String,
  timezone: Number
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  country: {id: Number, name: String}


});
```