# Mongoose schema with nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a document in my Schema that essentially works like a dictionary with an array of values (dates):

I want to use this to keep track of email correspondence I am sending users:

```
let d = {
    'generic-contact' = ['11/02/2019', '11/05/2020'],
    'update-profile' = ['1/01/2018']
}
```

I would then update this document field with something like:

```
let emailAddresses = ['joebloggs@yahoo.com', 'foobar@googlemail.com']

let recipients = await Profile.find({ email: { "$in" : emailAddresses } })
let emailTopic = 'newsletter03'

recipients.forEach(user => {

    user.correspondenceHistory[emailTopic].push(Date.now())
    user.save()

})
```

I want to do this so that I make sure that I don't send the same user the same email within a certain period of time.

However I can't work out how to set this up in my schema. Is this sort of structure possible?

I've tried many different structures for `correspondenceHistory`, but none of them have worked and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my schema as it stands:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    correspondenceHistory: { type: Array } ### Here ###
}, { discriminatorKey: 'accountType', retainKeyOrder: true, timestamps: true });
```

Comment: Will the keys of the dictionary remain same all the time?

Comment: No. I will create a new one for each new correspondence type

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030577/creating-a-dictionary-schema-with-mongoose

Comment: Kinda - thanks. So I guess it's not possible? `correspondenceHistory: { key: String, value: Date }` doesn't achieve what I want, as it just overwrite the document each time

Comment: Yeah, you can push whatever field you want to the object then, but it is at the cost of no validation by mongoose.

Comment: With Mongoose schemas you can do `correspondenceHistory: [ { key: String, value: Date } ]` . Or even define another schema `Corresponedence = mongoose.schema({ key: String, value: Date })` then  `correspondenceHistory: [ Correspondence ]`

Comment: @JeremyThille OK thanks. I've tried this, but it's less convenient than what I was hoping for.

Comment: @JeremyThille - although, just trying it again now I remember why i didn't like it.  `correspondenceHistory: [ { subject: String, date: Date } ]` when I do      `user.correspondenceHistory.push({'subject': data.subject, 'date': Date.now() });` I get an `_id` created for each entry. What's going on here? e.g. `{
    _id: 5eb8fe2bef0a4e11b104e71c,
    subject: 'Welcome to my website',
    date: 2020-05-11T07:26:00.000Z
  }
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254008/stop-mongoose-from-creating-id-property-for-sub-document-array-items

Comment: @fugu i think it creates a subdocument every time you push. subdocuments have their own _id automatically